# Код выводит результат дважды

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
a = int(input())
if (a%2 == 0):
    a = a // 2
    print(a)
if (a%2 != 0):
    print(a)
```

Код должен чётные числа делить на два, а нечётные оставлять как есть, и выводить на экран. Но когда я ввожу, например, "6", он выводит "3" два раза, а должен один. Что я не так сделал?

Comment: `if else` сделайте

Comment: a у вас равно 3, но ведь 3%2 не равно нулю, оттого второй раз и выводит

Comment: Так как исправить то?

Comment: Второй if исправьте на elif или вообще на else

Answer (score 3):

Читайте комментарии

```
a = int(input()) # а равно 6
if (a%2 == 0):   # 6%2 равно 0, заходим внутрь
    a = a // 2   # а теперь равно 3!!!
    print(a)     # печатаем 3
if (a%2 !=0):    # 3%2 не равно 0, заходим внутрь
    print(a)     # печатаем 3
```

Как исправить.

Так

```
a = int(input())
if (a % 2 == 0):
    print(a // 2)
if (a % 2 != 0):
    print(a)
```

Но лучше так

```
a = int(input())
if (a % 2 == 0):
    print(a // 2)
else:
    print(a)
```

PS. В следующий раз давайте вопросу заголовок, отражающий проблему. Тут в каждом вопросе программа работает неправильно.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что в строке

```
a = a // 2
```

вашего кода вы **переписываете содержание переменной `a`**, и когда это **новое** содержание (а не оригинальное, как вы хотели) удовлетворяет тесту в следующей строке

```
if (a%2 != 0):
```

то это новое значение тоже выводиться. :-(

Но вы хотите **или** первую возможность, **или** вторую возможность. Значит, просто вместо `if`-`if` использовать `if`-`else`:

```
a = int(input())
if (a % 2 == 0):
    a = a // 2
    print(a)
else:                # здесь разница
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(a // 2 if a%2 == 0 else a)`

а вообще, старайтесь не делать запись и чтение одной переменной несколько раз в перемешку -- багов меньше будет.